# How to fix View Pager Error.It only works after i press back button android

Tags: android

I am creating a demo project, i am New to android. I am facing problem with view pager. The page is frozen . It works only after I press back button

I removed the view pager and the app works fine.

**XMLLayout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
public class PortfolioFragment extends BaseFragment {

MyPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;



public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private int NUM_ITEMS = 3;
    String tabname[]=new String[]{"Apps","Websites","Upcoming"};

    MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new AppFragment();
            case 1:
                return new WebsitesFragment();
            default:
                return new UpcomingFragment();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabname[position];
    }

}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_portfolio, container, false);
    ViewPager vpPager =view.findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
    TabLayout tabLayout =view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_tab);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(vpPager);
    adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
    return view;

}
```

I expect it to work without pressing back

Comment: What does your Activity look like?

Comment: My MainActivity has bottom navigation drawer that moves to this portfolio fragment and here i want to add view pager with three tabs.